# Can a valid HTML comment tag contain an attribute-like syntax?

Tags: html

I'm trying to discern if the attribute syntax characters (quoted key-value pairs) are valid within HTML comments:

I can't tell if this is valid.  I looked at:

- http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view
- http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html

It appears that they probably are—except for a few references to "control characters".  I can't find a definition for control characters in the specification.

The specification only requires:

- comment open "<!--"
- text
- comment close "-->"

Most browsers and parsers support having a quoted key-value pair in a comment.  I've ran into a few issues with various open source libraries that can sometimes choke.

Comment: Comments are not tags and they should be completely opaque to an HTML parser. So apart from the restrictions meant to distinguish them you can put anything inside.

Comment: That's what I believe too.  But I can't find the answer in the HTML spec. The spec states "open" + text + "close" and allows for everything but "control characters" in the "text".  But I can't find a definition for them.

Comment: That refers to [Unicode control characters](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/control-characters.html#unicode).

Comment: Thanks!  That explains why i couldn't find the reference in the spec.

Comment: The two links are (effectively) broken. They both redirect to unspecific generic places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the attribute-like syntax contains no instances of the character sequences that are expressly forbidden in the spec, it's perfectly valid and won't break your comment in spectacular ways. For reference, here's what it says in the second link in your question:

> The text part of comments has the following restrictions:
>
> - must not start with a "`>`" character
> - must not start with the string "`->`"
> - must not contain the string "`--`"
> - must not end with a "`-`" character

This makes it easy to comment out most elements without having to change their content, unless they specifically contain the forbidden character sequences. For example, this is fine:

```
<!--<br clear="all">-->
```

Because we're talking about comments, as you may have guessed it'll simply be harmlessly ignored by the browser, as with any other comment content. That does not make your comment invalid *per se*.

Comment: Thanks.  I had seen that part.   My confusion was because the first link listed "control characters" as forbidden, but there was no reference to them.  @Jon noted [in a comment] that they referred to Unicode Control chars.

Comment: Also, FWIW, this *should* never make it to a browser.  We're storing some structured content within html comments; it's replaced with HTML on the fly - but stored within a comment in the database.  This allows for it to simply disappear if something breaks.

Answer (score 1):

No. Only elements have attributes,  and a comment is not an element.

That said, you can write many things in a comment. And you might to choose to call some of those things *attributes*. But in the context of parsing,  saying that is just confusing. In the context of HTML,  *attribute* has a specific meaning.

---

But why would you even want to do that? It seems you want to record some key-value pairs that you can parse later. HTML already has a feature for that: the `meta` element.

Comment: It might not need to be parsed as an attribute, but =-"' are valid characters within a comment.

Comment: @Jonathan You can put anything into a comment and call it an attribute if you wish; doesn't make it so in the spec.

Comment: I clarified the question.  I don't care about something parsing or interpreting key/value pairs as an attribute. I just want to know the validity of placing a quoted key/value pair in an HTML comment.